# My code with numba is slower than without numba

Tags: python, parallel-processing, numba, multitasking

My code with Numba is slower than without Numba, I don't know what's happening. Please instruct me.

```py
#with numba
import numpy as np
from numba import njit, prange
import time

(X_train, Y_train), (X_val, Y_val) = tf.keras.datasets.cifar10.load_data()

@njit(nopython= True)
def cal_padding(input, padding):
    output = np.zeros((input.shape[0]+ padding*2, input.shape[1]+ padding*2))
    output[ padding :  padding + input.shape[0],  padding :  padding + input.shape[1]] = input
    return output

@njit(nopython = True)
def conv_per_channel(data, kernel, padding = 1, stride = 1): #input ở đây là từng channel trong ảnh, kernel cũng là từng channel trong bộ
    h, w = data.shape
    data = cal_padding(data, padding)
    
    kernel_size = kernel.shape
    h_output = int((h - kernel_size[0] + 2*padding + stride) / stride)
    w_output = int((w - kernel_size[1] + 2*padding + stride) / stride)
    
    tranformed = np.zeros((h_output, w_output), dtype=data.dtype)
    h_kernel, w_kernel = kernel_size
    xRows = []
    yCols = []
    for i in range(w_kernel):
      for j in range(h_kernel):
        yCols.append(j)
        xRows.append(i)

    for i in range(h_output):
      for j in prange(w_output):
        root_pixel = [i,j]
        new_val = 0.0
        for k in range(w_kernel * h_kernel):
          pixel_in_filter_x = xRows[k]
          pixel_in_filter_y = yCols[k]

          pixel_in_input_x = pixel_in_filter_x + root_pixel[0]
          pixel_in_input_y = pixel_in_filter_y + root_pixel[1]
          new_val = new_val + (data[pixel_in_input_x, pixel_in_input_y] * kernel[pixel_in_filter_x][pixel_in_filter_y])
        if new_val > 255:
          new_val = 255
        elif new_val < 0:
          new_val = 0
        tranformed[i,j] = new_val
      
    return tranformed

X_train = np.transpose(X_train, (0,3,1,2))
X_train500 = X_train[0:500]
print(X_train[0][0].shape)

sobelX = np.array([[-1,0,1], [-2,0,2],[-1,0,1]])
start = time.time()
conv_per_channel(X_train[0][0], sobelX)
end = time.time()
print(end-start)
```

```py
#without numba
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

from numba import jit, prange
import time

(X_train, Y_train), (X_val, Y_val) = tf.keras.datasets.cifar10.load_data()

# @jit(nopython= True)
def cal_padding(input, padding):
    output = np.zeros((input.shape[0]+ padding*2, input.shape[1]+ padding*2))
    output[ padding :  padding + input.shape[0],  padding :  padding + input.shape[1]] = input
    return output

# @jit(nopython = True)
def conv_per_channel(data, kernel, padding = 1, stride = 1): #input ở đây là từng channel trong ảnh, kernel cũng là từng channel trong bộ
    h, w = data.shape
    data = cal_padding(data, padding)
    
    kernel_size = kernel.shape
    h_output = int((h - kernel_size[0] + 2*padding + stride) / stride)
    w_output = int((w - kernel_size[1] + 2*padding + stride) / stride)
    
    tranformed = np.zeros((h_output, w_output), dtype=data.dtype)
    h_kernel, w_kernel = kernel_size
    xRows = []
    yCols = []
    for i in range(w_kernel):
      for j in range(h_kernel):
        yCols.append(j)
        xRows.append(i)

    for i in range(h_output):
      for j in prange(w_output):
        root_pixel = [i,j]
        new_val = 0.0
        for k in range(w_kernel * h_kernel):
          pixel_in_filter_x = xRows[k]
          pixel_in_filter_y = yCols[k]

          pixel_in_input_x = pixel_in_filter_x + root_pixel[0]
          pixel_in_input_y = pixel_in_filter_y + root_pixel[1]
          new_val = new_val + (data[pixel_in_input_x, pixel_in_input_y] * kernel[pixel_in_filter_x][pixel_in_filter_y])
        if new_val > 255:
          new_val = 255
        elif new_val < 0:
          new_val = 0
        tranformed[i,j] = new_val
      
    return tranformed

X_train = np.transpose(X_train, (0,3,1,2))
X_train500 = X_train[0:500]
print(X_train[0][0].shape)

sobelX = np.array([[-1,0,1], [-2,0,2],[-1,0,1]])
start = time.time()
conv_per_channel(X_train[0][0], sobelX)
end = time.time()
print(end-start)
```

With Numba `@jit()` decorator this code run slower !
I tried with (parallel=True) or (cache = True) but it's even slower.

Just to help understand better the purpose of this code:

```
#with numba
(32, 32)
0.6485073566436768

#without numba
(32, 32)
0.007578611373901367
```

Comment: One thing you should try is running the numba code more than once. The first execution is going to include the time it takes it to jit it, and then after it will just used the cached compiled code. It's also possible that your use of prange is non-optimal. If the amount of work being done is small within the `prange` then the overhead of communicating between the treads may be greater than increase in calculation performance.

Comment: Note that `nopython=True` is useless with `njit` since it is already included in it. `prange` is useless without `parallel=True`. Reading past Numba questions can help to learn such a thing.

Answer (score 1):

This is something which is going to confuse the Numba optimizer:

```
    xRows = []
    yCols = []
    for i in range(w_kernel):
      for j in range(h_kernel):
        yCols.append(j)
        xRows.append(i)
...
          pixel_in_filter_x = xRows[k]
          pixel_in_filter_y = yCols[k]
```

Lists in Python are very flexible and can hold multiple different types of objects. The problem with that, from a performance perspective, is that Numba has no idea what type `pixel_in_filter_x` has. It needs that information to generate efficient code. Numba is built around optimizing access to NumPy array, not lists.

Lastly, I found that the `fastmath` flag made this code about 5% faster.

Example:

```
@jit(nopython= True)
def cal_padding_nb(input, padding):
    output = np.zeros((input.shape[0]+ padding*2, input.shape[1]+ padding*2))
    output[ padding :  padding + input.shape[0],  padding :  padding + input.shape[1]] = input
    return output

@jit(nopython = True, fastmath=True)
def conv_per_channel_nb(data, kernel, padding = 1, stride = 1):
    h, w = data.shape
    data = cal_padding_nb(data, padding)
    
    kernel_size = kernel.shape
    h_output = int((h - kernel_size[0] + 2*padding + stride) / stride)
    w_output = int((w - kernel_size[1] + 2*padding + stride) / stride)
    
    tranformed = np.zeros((h_output, w_output), dtype=data.dtype)
    h_kernel, w_kernel = kernel_size

    for i in range(h_output):
      for j in prange(w_output):
        new_val = 0.0
        for a in range(w_kernel):
          for b in range(h_kernel):
            pixel_in_filter_x = a
            pixel_in_filter_y = b

            pixel_in_input_x = pixel_in_filter_x + i
            pixel_in_input_y = pixel_in_filter_y + j
            new_val = new_val + (data[pixel_in_input_x, pixel_in_input_y] * kernel[pixel_in_filter_x][pixel_in_filter_y])
        if new_val > 255:
          new_val = 255
        elif new_val < 0:
          new_val = 0
        tranformed[i,j] = new_val
      
    return tranformed
```

I find this is much faster than the original non-numba version.

Timings, ignoring first iteration of numba version:

```
Original, without numba: 11.3 ms ± 92.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
Numba, without lists: 31 µs ± 824 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

This is roughly 360 times faster.